# Why does Chrome sometimes logs only the preflight request (and not the actual GET) when using CORS?

Tags: google-chrome, cors

UPDATE: If I go back to 'All' tab and then back to 'XHR' I see both requests, so I guess it's some kind of chrome bug?

The GET request completes successfully but I cannot inspect the response. This occurs randomly in some of the endpoints of my api.

Firefox always logs the response.

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. Seeing them in their entirety when in the 'All' tab. The 'XHR' tab lists only the OPTIONS CORS pre-flight requests. Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)

Comment: It's indeed a sneaky Chrome Developer Tools bug.

Answer (score 22):

You can always have a better view of the network communication via

> chrome://net-internals/#events

Maybe you'll find something blocking it before reaching the dev tools..

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't see anything wrong there http://i6.minus.com/jhjtuzpRmQCGb.jpg

Comment: @stream7 The second one is red.. You can click on it to check its contents

Comment: you are right. I have no idea what this error is about. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bltugv4pt484pxa/error.jpg
However, this error occurs even when the response is logged normally.....

Comment: Try to reproduce on incognito mode. Maybe an extension is messing with your requests..

Answer (score 1):

On the network tab, you can remove the tick infront of this menu `3rd-party-request`

[image]